# change the title of a backButtonItem in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, backbarbuttonitem

I´m just a beginner in Swift and i don´t get it.
Why doesn't change the title of my backBarButtonItem after the push segue?

I tried it with this code in the viewDidLoad:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use `!` not `?`. `!` is used for getting value from optional or unwrapping the optional

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.title = "Back"
```

Comment: Then, the app will crash... Unfortunately

Comment: The Debugger says: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value